# ECMAscript - grab field value from specific id number

Tags: list, javascript

I'm trying to grab the value from field1 with a specific id number, do a mathematical computation and update the same id number with the new value and update field1. I'm unsure on how to grab the field value with the specific id number. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Do I use the getItemById() method? If so, how do I grab the field1 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example should help..

```
//Get the list item from the Announcements list whose Id is 4. Note that this is the ID of the item in the list, not a reference to its position in the collection.
var itemId = 4;   
var targetListItem;

function runCode() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
   var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
   targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
   clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Title');
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
   var field1Value = targetListItem.get_item('field1'); //Internal Name of the Field

   alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item Field1 Value is: ' + field1Value);

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Reference:

[How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx)